# How to print probabilities for categorical outcome using xgboost?

Tags: r, categorical-data, xgboost

I have a training set that looks like

```
Name       Day         Area         X    Y    Month Night
ATTACK    Monday   LA           -122.41 37.78   8      0
VEHICLE  Saturday  CHICAGO      -1.67    3.15   2      0
MOUSE     Monday   TAIPEI       -12.5    3.1    9      1
```

`Name` is the outcome/dependent variable. I converted `Name`, `Area` and `Day` into factors, but I wasn't sure if I was supposed to for `Month` and `Night`, which only take on integer values 1-12 and 0-1, respectively.

I then tried to convert this is into a `model.matrix` and then run `xgboost`

```
m<-model.matrix(~Area + Day + X + Y + Month +Night, data = train)
num.class=length(levels(train$Name))
levels(train$Name)=1:num.class
y = as.matrix(as.integer(train$Name)-1)
param <- list("objective" = "multi:softprob",
          "eval_metric" = "mlogloss", "nthread" = 4,
          "num_class" = num.class, "max_depth" = 16, "eta" = 0.3)
bst <- xgboost(param=param, data=m, label=y, nrounds=min.merror.idx, verbose=0)
m.test <- model.matrix(~ Area + Day + X + Y + Month +Night, data =testDF)
pred <- predict(bst, m.test)
```

However,`head(pred)` just shows a bunch of prob numbers

```
[1] 0.007272065 0.207123533 0.003311855 0.003352652
```

The `Name` variable can take on 39 different values. `nrow(test)` gives over 80000, and `nrow(test)`*39 is the same as `length(pred)`. I'm not sure what `pred` is saying. Assuming `Name` is ordered as `[ATTACK, VEHICLE, ..]`, it saying that for the 1st row `prob(ATTACK)=.00727`, `prob(VEHICLE)=.207`, ...? Or is it saying `prob(ATTACK_1strow)=.00727`, `prob(ATTACK_2ndrow)=.207`,...?

Assuming `pred` is the former, how can I then modify `pred` so that it looks like below?

```
    prob.ATTACK prob.VEHICLE ...
1   .00727      .207         ...
...
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you do train an `xgboost` classifier with `"objective" = "multi:softprob"`  you are actually training seperate binary models for each class.    So in total for your example you have `num.class` * `nrow(data)` total predictions.

To formulate this into a matrix (there are lots of ways) :

`matrix(pred, ncol = num.class, byrow = T)`

note that you have to be careful that you populate the matrix properly, the example I gave will populate the matrix row-wise. Youll be left with  matrix where each row is a training example, and each column is a probability for  a given class.

from `?xgb.train`

> multi:softprob same as softmax, but output a vector of ndata *
>   nclass, which can be further reshaped to ndata, nclass matrix. The
>   result contains predicted probabilities of each data point belonging
>   to each class.

Answer (score 0):

```
pred <- data.frame(t(matrix(pred, nrow = num.class, ncol = length(pred)/num.class)))
```